# Use server date instead of new Date() in React

Tags: reactjs, yup

I have minimum date and maximum date control on more than one page on the yup side. My login service returns processDate: 12.26.2020 response and I want to pass the processDate parameter instead of using new Date() to all controls. How should I go? I am using context for state management.

Comment: Create a wrapper date picker component, read the date returned by the server (either context/localstorage) and use the date picker component wherever you need in your app

Answer (score 0):

I think you need more code to get a more specific answer, there are a few patterns you could use:

- Use getState/setState in parent instead of passing it down - best
- Use a utility function in the components to convert the string, to prevent passing down Date()
- Use something like Redex to manage state

Sounds like the issue is more prop passing than anything else?